# Setting listbox highlight colour to null

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />                   
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

The above code is intended to prevent any highlight colour being used as a 'selection indicator' for my list box items. My program has a completely white background and I intend on using some custom animation to represent the selection instead. The above code does remove the traditional blue highlight but it also makes the text (within the item container) completely disappear so all I see is a white item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style, in the IsSelected trigger, add a Setter to set the Foreground to the desired color instead of white.  I usually do this in the ItemContainerStyle, but it should work in your ListBoxItem style just as well.